# What do you call a wall at the center of a subway platform, displaying some information?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the subway stations of Vienna there are "info-walls", on which

- map of the city,
- plan of the subway,
- emergency communicator and
- some other information (such as terms and conditions)

is displayed (see 2 red rectangles in the image below).

[image: Info-Wall in the subway station of Vienna]

What are these things called in English?

Comment: Information boards? Passenger notification panels? Advertisement spaces? I think the answer varies from place to place. Good question and good luck on getting a generic answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic term, but 'double-sided information boards' would probably be understood by everyone. 'Panels' instead of 'boards' if they are electronic displays.

Comment: I would call it a billboard.

Comment: I'd call it a panel, electronic or not, if the display area is a panel. (Inset, distinct) Display, panel, kiosk, and board all have slight differences but apply to some extent. (Kiosk least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call that kind of thing a *kiosk*.

One [definition of kiosk](https://www.google.com/#q=kiosk+define) is:

> a small structure in a public area used for providing information or displaying advertisements, often incorporating an interactive display screen or screens.

Comment: To me, a kiosk needs to be three-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, they can be. Look on [Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=kiosk&prmd=isavn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDzITy44rPAhXLSSYKHYq4AzUQ_AUICCgB&biw=320&bih=460)

Comment: Well, well. I always imagined a kiosk as something that can contain at least one person. Thanks.

Comment: I think that *is* the definition and marketing folks have taken liberties... Causing drift. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kiosk